# How to update child element in type-orm when one-to-many relations but without putting manually updated data

Tags: typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

{
"NAME": "B",
"NAME_EN": "abc",
"DLRS_CODE": "123 ",
"LOC_UPAZILA_ID": 1,
"LOC_CIRCLE_ID":1,
"LOC_THANA_ID":1,
"ROW_STATUS": 1,
"JL_NUMBERS":[
{
"MOUZA_NAME": "new",
"JL_NUMBER":1,
"SURVEY_ID":1,
"DIVISION_NAME":"A",
"DISTRICT_NAME":"B",
"UPAZILA_NAME":"C",
"THANA_NAME":"D"
},
{
"MOUZA_NAME": "kjkj",
"JL_NUMBER":1,
"SURVEY_ID":2,
"DIVISION_NAME":"A",
"DISTRICT_NAME":"B",
"UPAZILA_NAME":"C",
"THANA_NAME":"D"
}
]
}

{
"NAME": "updated",
"NAME_EN": "abc",
"DLRS_CODE": "123 ",
"LOC_UPAZILA_ID": 1,
"LOC_CIRCLE_ID":1,
"LOC_THANA_ID":1,
"ROW_STATUS": 1,
"JL_NUMBERS":[
{
"MOUZA_NAME": "new",
"JL_NUMBER":1,
"SURVEY_ID":1,
"DIVISION_NAME":"A",
"DISTRICT_NAME":"B",
"UPAZILA_NAME":"C",
"THANA_NAME":"D"
},
{
"MOUZA_NAME": "kjkj",
"JL_NUMBER":1,
"SURVEY_ID":2,
"DIVISION_NAME":"A",
"DISTRICT_NAME":"B",
"UPAZILA_NAME":"C",
"THANA_NAME":"D"
},
{
"MOUZA_NAME": "updated",
"JL_NUMBER":1,
"SURVEY_ID":2,
"DIVISION_NAME":"A",
"DISTRICT_NAME":"B",
"UPAZILA_NAME":"C",
"THANA_NAME":"D"
}
]
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.